# Custom uicollectionview - pass data

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView that use a custom cell:

```
[_collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.articolo = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I want to pass the object articolo to my cell, so I create a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *articolo;
```

but if I try to read the property in one of this method:

```
@implementation CollectionViewCell
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {NSLog(@"Articolo: %@",_articolo);}
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {NSLog(@"Articolo: %@",_articolo);}
    return self;
}
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    NSLog(@"Articolo: %@",_articolo);
}
```

I get always a null value, where is the error? how can I pass this object to my cell?

Comment: it's normal because your variable is not initialized  in the init methods but after that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may help u.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.articolo =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
             return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfect, you will always get null value in any of the above method because it is called when your cell is initialized.

You can get value by putting setter method like this.

```
-(void)setArticolo:(NSMutableDictionary *)articolo {

  _articolo = articolo;

}
```

Comment: I use this method and with some changes I get what I want...but why I can't see my data in one of the 3 method?